# calculating an integral $\int\frac{x \ln x}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}dx $

Tags: calculus

I tried to do subtition and to integrate by parts, unsuccessfully.

$\int\frac{x \ln x}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}dx
 $

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+y}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$ with $y=x^2$, was easy to integrate and its integral is rational.

On the other hand, $(\ln(x))'=\frac{1}{x}$ is rational.

Therefore, integration by parts rationalizes the integrand.

$$\int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}\ln(x)=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{x}$$

The last integral you can do by expanding in simple fractions and all of that.

Comment: Do you have a link that explains how to do the guessing of the fractions in the end? I don't understand how to guess it.

Comment: @NeilRauch Guessing which fractions?

Comment: @NeilRauch These $\frac{1}{(x^3+x)} = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{(x^2+1)}$?

Comment: I mean some general way how to find it - cause I have not understood it yet.

Comment: Start from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) maybe. There are so many places from where to learn it. Google *partial fraction decomposition*.